# How to check if some string is combination of values from two separate columns i.e tables PHP MySql

Tags: php, mysql, clean-urls

I need the least expensive way to check if my url slug is formed from the values from two separate columns from two separate tables.

I will use dummy example with stores and locations to make this more human readable.
I have the following url:

```
www.domain.com/store-location
```

This could be, for example:

```
www.domain.com/three-words-store-chicago or
www.domain.com/nicestore-new-york-or-some-neighbourhood-with-more-words or
www.domain.com/oneword-oneword
```

(you get the idea)

Stores are located in table called stores, and locations in the table called locations. 
All the combinations are possible in theory. 
So, I would need some clever mysql query combined with php which will check if my slug (what goes after .com/) is the exact combination of store+location. So, to make it more descriptive:

```
url: www.domain.com/cool-store-los-angeles
```

Check is there "cool-store" in the table stores.slug_stores and is there "los-angeles" in the table locations.slug_location. The number of words of both is undefined as you can see above, so I don't have any possible delimiter.

IT MUST BE THE LEAST EXPENSIVE WAY because both tables tables have around 1000 lines. PLEASE HELP AND THANK YOU GUYS!

ps. IMPORTANT: I MUSTN'T CHANGE URLS IN ANY WAY

Edit: This is real project, website. Depending on the url i.e. slug I return some view with data. So I need to check for www.domain.com/nicestore-nicecity if Nicestore and Nicecity exist in tables stores and locations, and if not, or if anything else is there like www.domain.com/nicestore-nicecityBLABLA to kill that page with 404. Otherwise, if there is Nicestore and Nicecity to return some page populated with related data. I tried so far to make separate table with formed slugs like "nicestore-nicecity" and to use it for queries "SELECT whatever FROM slugs WHERE whatever = 'nicestore-nicecity' and if there is line return whatever I need to show the page ... Simplified... But, this separate table is hard to maintain. If nicestore moves to uglycity, or if it changes name, or if you add a new store or new city. I hope I was more clear now ;-)

Comment: _"I MUSTN'T CHANGE URLS IN ANY WAY"_  you've really dug a difficult hole for yourself. Would have been much easier as `/store-name/location-name`

Comment: @Phil, I wasn't digging this whole myself, I inherited it :-(. I agree with you, and when I was "digging" on some other project I did exactly what you said. ;-)

Comment: Have you tried anything yet? If so, you should add your attempts to your question. I have some ideas but none of them are particularly efficient though sifting through a million possible combinations probably wouldn't be _too_ taxing on your DB

Comment: @Phil I have separate table called urls with already joined combinations of stores and locations. It is hard to maintain, any change of address, name, new stores, new cities...So, I hoped some php/mysql guru might help :-D

Comment: Why not make it a [`VIEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html)? That way it's always up-to-date

Comment: Also, if this is for maintaining some sort of derived table, why does it need to be efficient?

Comment: @Phil view sounds interesting, I've never used it before. How could it be implemented in this example? It must be efficient since it checks what sort of page to return or to give 404 (website)

Comment: Sounds like you need to [edit your question](https://stackoverflow.com/posts/54412715/edit) with **all** the details. Include the process / logic flow as I'm confused about whether this is some real-time, request-based solution you need or some offline _"update this `URLS` table"_ task. Where do the request URLs come from?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm assuming that you don't have any `id` values on which to `JOIN` your tables, and that you don't have the ability to create such values. In that case, since your store/location combination could be as short as `oneword-oneword`, the first and last words of the slug are about as much as you can search on. You can extract the start and end parts of the slug using [`SUBSTRING_INDEX`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/string-functions.html#function_substring-index) and use that to narrow the set of matches in each table *before* you try and compare the whole string. In my example, I'm using an SQL variable to store the slug:

```
SET @store = 'cool-store-los-angeles'
SELECT *
FROM (SELECT * 
      FROM stores 
      WHERE store LIKE CONCAT(SUBSTRING_INDEX(@store, '-', 1), '%')) s
JOIN (SELECT * 
      FROM locations 
      WHERE location LIKE CONCAT('%', SUBSTRING_INDEX(@store, '-', -1))) l
WHERE CONCAT(s.store, '-', l.location) = @store
```

This will return all data associated with `cool-store-los-angeles` assuming that such a store exists.

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=01d6f672238f0f1c7f1d7b891e3daa6e)

Answer (score 1):

Here's what I know about your system...

1. You have a `stores` table with column `slug_stores`
2. You have a `locations` table with column `slug_location`

I'm going to assume that each table has an `id` column of some type. I'm also going to assume they have a *many-to-many* relationship using a third junction table, something like

```sql
CREATE TABLE store_locations (
  store_id <type>,
  location_id <type>,
  PRIMARY KEY (store_id, location_id),
  FOREIGN KEY (store_id) REFERENCES stores(id),
  FOREIGN KEY (location_id) REFERENCES locations(id)
);
```

If you don't have this sort of relationship defined, I really don't know how you maintain your store locations.

---

What I would suggest is creating a [`VIEW`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/create-view.html) to calculate and represent your URLs. For example...

```sql
CREATE VIEW store_location_urls AS
SELECT
  sl.store_id,
  sl.location_id,
  CONCAT_WS('-', s.slug_stores, l.slug_location) AS slug
FROM store_locations sl
INNER JOIN stores s ON sl.store_id = s.id
INNER JOIN locations l ON sl.location_id = l.id;
```

Now you can use this view to do the following...

1. Check if a request URL slug is valid

   ```sql
   SELECT store_id, location_id FROM store_location_urls WHERE slug = ?
   ```

   If this returns a record, you can then further query the `stores` and `locations` tables for whatever extra data you need to render your page (or even just join them in the original query). Otherwise, use

   ```php
   http_response_code(404);
   ```
2. Get all the URL slugs for a particular store

   ```sql
   SELECT slug FROM store_location_urls WHERE store_id = ?
   ```
3. Similarly, you could get all the URL slugs for a particular location

---

An extra note... due to concatenating strings, any indexes you have on `stores.slug_stores` and `locations.slug_location` will be useless with the above `VIEW`. The alternative is to use a real derived table (like what you currently have) and maintain it with triggers.

Answer (score -1):

I think you can query like following in mysql and if do check in php afterwards. From your description, it doesn't sound like there is any join possible between those tables so, union is required, i think.

`select col1,col2 from stores where slug_stores = ?
union
select col1,col2 from locations where slug_location = ?`